# Mouse double-click time is too short in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, mouse

In mouse settings it doesn't allow me to lengthen the time.  Only very basic settings are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

To change the double-click interval in Lubuntu (confirmed to be working on 14.04):

1. Create a (hidden) file:

   ```
   ~/.gtkrc-2.0
   ```

   (`~/` is your home directory, files starting with `.` are hidden by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make hidden files visible)
2. Open the file with Leafpad / run in a terminal window:

   ```
   leafpad ~/.gtkrc-2.0
   ```
3. add a line to the file:

   ```
   gtk-double-click-time=600
   (or any other value you'd like)
   ```
4. Close the file, log out and back in, test if the value is what you like.

Comment: I suggest using `~/.gtkrc-2.0.mine` because ~/.gtkrc-2.0 can be overwritten by certain programs: _# DO NOT EDIT! This file will be overwritten by LXAppearance.\n
# Any customization should be done in ~/.gtkrc-2.0.mine instead. _
You could also edit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini to ensure that your settings apply to gtk3 apps as well.

Comment: The window manager GUI also has the facility to alter double-click speed re. the title bar. Open `obconf` (present by default in Lubuntu) and click on the "Mouse" tab.

Comment: More reading: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Mouse and http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=501

Comment: @DKBose The link you mention describes exactly the procedure as in my answer: *"To do so, you will need to edit a file called .gtkrc-2.0 in your home directory. If you don't see this file, make sure you have enabled viewing of hidden files and folders (or use ls -a in your terminal window instead of plain ls). If you still don't see this file, you will need to create the file."* The procedure is also mentionend in other sources for 14.04.

Comment: @DKBose The content of the second link you mention is six years old. The menu you mention is not available in 14.04. But even then, it sais: *" If it does exit, read it before you proceed -- it may advise you to use ".gtkrc-2.0.mine" instead."* Obviously it doesn't, since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @fritzzwicky did you manage?